# Quick Sort, sort in Descending order, instead of Ascending

Tags: c#, quicksort

i have written a Quick Sort Algorithm and it sorts the array in ascending order. I am trying to alter the program so it sorts the array in descending order. Sounds simple enough, but i'm not sure which areas of the program to alter. Thanks.

```
public static void Quick_Sort(ref double[] data, int left,int right, ref int count)
    {
        int i;      
        int j;      
        double pivot;      
        double temp;        
        i = left;      
        j = right;     
        pivot = data[(left + right) / 2];                 
            do         
            {
                while ((data[i] < pivot) && (i < right)) i++;       
                count++;
                while ((pivot < data[j]) && (j > left)) j--;        
                count++;
                ;
                if (i <= j)     
                {
                    temp = data[i];     
                    data[i] = data[j];    
                    data[j] = temp;     
                    i++;        
                    j--;       
                    count++;
                }
            } while (i <= j);       
            if (left < j) Quick_Sort(ref data, left, j, ref count, order);     
            if (i < right) Quick_Sort(ref data, i, right, ref count, order);
}    



 public static void QuickSort(ref double[] data, int size, int order)
    {

        int count = 0;      
        Quick_Sort(ref data, 0, data.Length - 1, ref count, order);    
        Console.WriteLine("\n    Quick Sort\n    Number of Elements: {0}\n    Executed {1} times\n\n    Worse-Case: O(n^2)\n    Best-Case: O(n log n)\n    Average-Case: O(n log n)",size,  count);     
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the while loops in your do-while loop to:

```
while ((data[i] > pivot) && (i < right)) i++;
count++;
while ((pivot > data[j]) && (j > left)) j--;
count++;
```

In the first loop change `data[i] < pivot` to `data[i] > pivot` and in the second loop change `pivot < data[j]` to `pivot > data[j]`.

[DEMO HERE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Z1Le61)

Comment: gives me a StackOverflowException

Comment: I tried it and it works from me, can you post how you are calling the Quick_Sort method

Comment: Sure, ive added it to the bottom of the post.

Comment: I added a link DEMO HERE where you can check the code on a online compiler

Comment: Legend!, i had an issue on my end. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Craig I am glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You should alter signs while comparing to pivot.

```
while ((data[i] > pivot) && (i < right)) 
{
    i++;       
}

count++;

while ((pivot < data[j]) && (j > left)) 
{
    j--;        
}

count++;
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this suffice you? (after sorting)

```
var dataReversed = data.Reverse().ToArray();
```